# Convert vector to 2D grid display: How to find a rectangle who's (integer) area most closely matches a given integer?

Tags: r

From the inspiration of Hans Rosling,
https://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_shows_the_best_stats_you_ve_ever_seen#t-103612

I am trying to represent statistical information in an easily understood and entertaining graphical form. As a step to doing this I would like to solve this problem.

Given an interger `X`, I want to find a rectangle `R` whose area (l * w) most closely matches `X`/

For example, if `X=7` , then `R` should have `l=2` & `w=4` (area = 8).

I tried:

```
len1 <- 7

m1 <-  ceiling(sqrt(len1))
m1


m2 <-  ceiling(len1 /m1)
m2
```

But this gives 3 * 3 whereas the best solution is 2*4.

Comment: What are the rules that govern what rectangles can be used?   1 x 7 rectangle fits better.

Comment: Closest to a filled square with fewest spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example and might work in general

```
# get the first dimension
dim1 <- floor(sqrt(len1))
# fill out the second dimension
dim2 <- (len1 %/% dim1 + (len1 %% dim1 != 0))
```

---

To test, put this into a function

```
dimGet <- function(x) {
  dim1 <- floor(sqrt(x))
  dim2 <- (x %/% dim1 + (x %% dim1 != 0))

  return(c(dim1=dim1, dim2=dim2))
}
```

Now, run it against 1 through 10

```
sapply(1:10, dimGet)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
dim1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    3     3
dim2    1    2    3    2    3    3    4    4    3     4
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear what you want but this may work

```
getrect = function(x = 7){
    f = floor(sqrt(x))
    if(f^2 == x){
        return(c(f,f))
    }
    d = max(2,(f - 500)):(f + 500) #decrease 500 to improve speed, increase 500 to improve accuracy
    d = data.frame(t(combn(d,2)))   
    d$M = d$X1 * d$X2
    d = d[d$M >= x,]
    d$diff = abs(d$X1-d$X2)
    d$M_diff = abs(d$M-x)
    d = d[with(d, order(M_diff, diff)), ]
    return( c(d[1,1], d[1,2]) )
}

sapply(1:25, getrect)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
#[1,] 1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    3    2     3     3     3     3     3     4     3     3     4     4     3     4     4     4     5    
#[2,] 1    3    3    2    3    3    4    4    3    5     4     4     5     5     5     4     6     6     5     5     7     6     6     6     5
```